# How do I remove a drawer from Whitney desk (Pottery Barn)

Tags: drawers, removal

I have a desk drawer that is not staying closed, so I want to take the drawer out and adjust the gliders or something, but I can't figure out how to remove the drawer.

The drawer is on a Whitney desk unit that I got from Pottery Barn:
[image]

The drawer has metal rails on the side.  It doesn't have rollers and doesn't appear to have any levers.  I'm stumped.

[image]

Comment: A close-up picture of the extended drawer slide might be a lot more useful that the provided picture. Lacking a picture to see details in, sometimes they just lift up to release.

Comment: ... and sometimes there's a spring that needs to be depressed. Agreed, we need pix of the slide parts.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll add more pictures shortly.

Comment: Is that fully extended in the photo? The button to press would typically be somewhere in the dark area in the track, but it's difficult to see. You have to push or pull a release mechanism in there to allow the drawer to slide past the stops all the way off the track.

Comment: yes, this is pulled out as far as I can.  I've tried poking a screw driver in there to see if I can make something release, but no luck.

Comment: This diagram should help, but the mechanism is difficult to reach. http://www.potterybarnkids.com/pkimgs/ab/images/i/201615/0007/images/design-studio/pdf/instructions/larkin_desk.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem with the PB Bedford desk.  I called the furniture dept. and they said on the drawer slides there's a lever and to push up on the one on the left and down on the one on the right and then pull the drawer out.  The drawer slides in your pic look just like mine, so maybe this will work.  I didn't have any luck, but it seems like a 2-person job.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will give this a try and see if I have any luck.